# Active Users SQL query

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to graph active users in a webapp. My database consists of two main tables, `user` and `task`. `task` has a `user_id`.

My definition of **active users:** is *a user who has created more than 2 tasks within two weeks of a given end date*.

So, I need an SQL query that gives me the number of active users between a given start and end date. I was able to do this by putting the query inside a loop, pulling the results each time, but I'd love to be able to do it in a single query.

The returned data should be something like:

```
Date         Count
2010-01-01   4
2010-01-02   3
2010-01-03   5
```

Edit to clarify desired dataset.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t.taskdate, COUNT(DISTINCT u.user_id)
    FROM user u
        INNER JOIN task t
            ON u.user_id = t.user_id
                AND t.taskdate BETWEEN DATE_ADD(@EndDate, INTERVAL -2 WEEK) AND @EndDate
    GROUP BY t.taskdate
    ORDER BY t.taskdate
```

Comment: +1 (the least I could do as I've used your solution of the date interval to fix my answer)

Comment: @Lieven: As long as you're borrowing my code, you may want to borrow from my most recent edit. I fixed the DATE_ADD to use MySQL syntax.

Comment: This is a great start. What I did not clarify is that I need the total for each day in between a start and end date. For example: 2010-01-01 = 4, 2010-01-02 = 3, 2010-01-03 = 5, ...

Comment: @Ian Silber: I edited my answer to incorporate the new requirement.

Comment: @Joe thanks! One thing though, would this allow me to specify a start date? For example, start 2010-01-01, end 2010-12-31, returning data for each day that has at least one active user. Thanks!

Comment: @Ian Silber: Yes. You could replace the `DATE_ADD(@EndDate, INTERVAL -2 WEEK)` with any `@StartDate`.

Comment: @Joe It's more complicated than that. Need to specify start and end date, and return active users for each day between that range. And an active user is defined as someone who has > 1 task in the last two weeks from X end date.

Answer (score 1):

A `GROUP BY` with a [`HAVING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) clause should be sufficient to get all users

```
SELECT u.user_id
FROM   user u
       INNER JOIN task t ON t.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE  date BETWEEN DATEADD(week, -2, <EndDate>) AND <EndDate>

GROUP BY
       u.user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

and to get the total count wrap it up in an another statement

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   (
         SELECT u.user_id
         FROM   user u
                INNER JOIN task t ON t.user_id = u.user_id
         WHERE  date BETWEEN DATEADD(week, -2, <EndDate>) AND <EndDate>
         GROUP BY
                u.user_id
         HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
       ) u
```

**Edit**

Fixed the 2 week requirement using the code posted by Joe.

Comment: I think you need to modify the "date BETWEEN <startdate> AND <enddate>" to match the condition "within 2 weeks" other than that it will work.

Comment: @sh_kamalh: fixed the condition.

Comment: This is awesome - however, I need to be able to specify a start and end date and, for each date between the start and end pull the number of active users for that given day.

Answer (score 0):

This is not for mysql but it could work (I am not sure of task_date + 14).

```
select *
from user u
where (select count(*) form task t where t.user_id = u.user_id and t.task_date + 14 > @end_date) > 2
```

The inner query `select count...` gets the tasks for the user that have been created 14 or less days before the given end_date