# SQL: Count Users with Activity in the Past Week

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to count the number of users who have had at least two sessions within 7 days of OR ten in 30 days of all dates.

My data is as follow:

```
Date        UserID  SessionID 
1/1/2013    Bob1234    1
2/1/2013    Bob1234    2
2/2/2013    Bob1234    3
2/3/2013    Cal5678    4
```

Which would result in the following table (only select dates shown)

```
Date    CountActiveUsers
1/1/2013    1
1/15/2013   0
2/2/2013    1
2/3/2013    2
```

The real data set has values for all dates in a continuous data range and the results table should have an entry for every date.

SessionIDs are unique and a UserID always refers to the same person.

So far I have two queries that do something close-ish. The first returns the count of sessions in the past week by user:

```
SELECT Count(
d.[SessionID]
) As SessionPastWeek
      ,m.[UserID]
      ,m.[Date]
  FROM [Cosmos].[dbo].[Sessions_tbl] as m
  Inner Join [Cosmos].[dbo].[Sessions_tbl] as d 
on m.[UserID2] = d.[UserID] AND 
--Between does not work here for some reason
d.[Date] <= m.[Date] AND
d.[Date] > DATEADD(d,-7,m.[date])

  Group By m.[UserID]
      ,m.[Date]
```

The other is from the following link which count the number of active users in a given date
[Active Users SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318186/active-users-sql-query)

I am in SQL Server 2012

I am having trouble combining the two.

Edit for clarification: the query I need likely won't have any getdate() or similar as I need to know how many users fit the 'active' criteria on Jan 1, today, and all the dates inbetween.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Which RDBMS u are using? SQL SERVER 2008? OR MYSQL? or Other?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to add a HAVING clause:

```
HAVING COUNT(d.[SessionID]) >= 2
```

On your 10 in 30 query, just change your DATEADD() to have 30 days, and change the HAVING clause to be >= 10.

```
    SELECT COUNT(d.[SessionID]) AS SessionPastPeriod
        , m.[UserID]
        , m.[Date]
    FROM Sessions_tbl AS m
        INNER JOIN Sessions_tbl as d
            ON m.UserID = d.UserID
            AND d.[Date] <= m.[Date]
            AND d.[Date] > DATEADD(d,-7,m.[Date])
    GROUP BY m.UserID
        , m.[Date]
    HAVING COUNT(d.[SessionID]) >= 2
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are too close.

```
SELECT Count(d.[SessionID]) As SessionPastWeek
      ,m.[UserID]
      ,m.[Date]
FROM [Cosmos].[dbo].[Sessions_tbl] as m
Inner Join [Cosmos].[dbo].[Sessions_tbl] as d on m.[UserID2] = d.[UserID]
--Between does not work here for some reason
where --ADD where clause
d.[Date] <= getdate() AND
d.[Date] > DATEADD(d,-7,getdate())
Group By m.[UserID],m.[Date]
having Count(d.[SessionID])>1 --The magical clause for you.
```

Comment: Don't think this implements "two sessions within 7 days OR ten in the past 30 day"

Comment: @Andomar **`with 7 days`**.

Comment: It looks like the code for this is intending to only find activity within the most recent week, not for all weeks prior to all dates. 

It is also returning Null results for me. Query executes successfully, but with no data.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  count(*)
from    (
        select  UserID
        ,       sum(case when Date between dateadd(day, -7, getdate()) and getdate()
                    then 1 end) as LastWeek
        ,       sum(case when Date between dateadd(day, -30, getdate()) and getdate()
                    then 1 end) as Last30Days
        from    Sessions_tbl
        group by
                UserID
        ) SubQueryAlias
where   LastWeek >= 2
        or Last30Days >= 10
```

Comment: It looks like the code for this is intending to only find activity within the most recent week, not for all weeks prior to all dates. I need to know how many users fit the 'active' criteria on Jan 1 and today.

Comment: Updated so you can use it for dates in the past as well.  For example, replace all occurrences of `getdate()` with `2013-01-01`

Answer (score 0):

The following query works:

```
Select
Count(UserID) As CountUsers
,[Date]
From(  
    SELECT COUNT(d.[SessionID]) AS SessionPastPeriod
        , m.[Date]
        , m.UserID
    FROM [Sessions_tbl] AS m
        INNER JOIN [Sessions_tbl]  as d
            ON m.UserID = d.UserID
            AND d.[Date] <= m.[Date]
            AND d.[Date] > DATEADD(d,-7,m.[Date])
    GROUP BY 
         m.UserID
         ,m.[Date]
    HAVING COUNT(d.[SessionID]) >= 2) SQ
    Group By [Date]
```