# Find all the users from a table who have done atleast one activity every week in past one year

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two `tables user [user_id,name]` and `task [task_id,title,fk_user]`. I want to find out all the users from user table who have done atleast one activity every week in past 1year.
Example

**user**

```
  user_id(primaryKey) name   created_at
     1                Alice  2018-05-03 10:22:56
     2                Bob    2018-05-04 10:22:56
```

**Task**

```
    task_id(primaryKey) title fk_user created_at
      1                  t1     1      2018-05-04 10:22:56
      2                  t2     1      2018-05-04 10:23:56
      3                  t1     2      2018-05-04 10:24:56
      4                  t2     2      2018-05-04 10:24:56
```

**Result**

```
    user_every_week_in_past_year 
      1  
      2
```

Comment: Can you show us the table schema and some sample data so we don't have to guess at what your data looks like, please?

Comment: What have you try so far ? There is no time related in the 2 tables .

Comment: It would be a very interesting question, if you asked it properly. I'd like to help, the sql query would be challenging to figure out, but there are no details in the question to work with. Post the schema, where/how do you store time?

Comment: I have added table details, I was trying to do it using `having` close but thing is I can find who did at least one activity last one week but not of complete year.

Comment: Is there some data in the task table for every week of the year? Or are there gaps?

Comment: Task table is basically recording activity, whenever user perform an activity it is recorded into task table. Now I wants to find out all user who have done at least one activity every week.

Comment: My question has some similarity with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708295/sql-count-users-with-activity-in-the-past-week , but there is some difference.

Comment: What you want result .. please show those data too

Comment: I want all the user_id who fall into those condition. Have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I derived this answer from @Nick answer,

```
SELECT fk_user as user_every_week_in_past_year from (
   SELECT fk_user,count(task_id) as activties FROM `task` 
   where created_at > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 52 WEEK 
   group by fk_user, WEEK(created_at)) ua 
   group by fk_user having count(activties) = 52;
```

I didn't feel the need of join with user table to find the records. Subquery finds all task as activities done by a user in every week past one year, which is again group by user id to achieve the required result.

Comment: I guess I over-engineered the answer! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should work... it's hard to be certain without complete sample data:

```
SELECT name
FROM (SELECT u.name, COUNT(t.task_id) AS tasks
      FROM user u
      JOIN task t
      ON t.fk_user = u.user_id
      WHERE t.created_at > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 52 WEEK
      GROUP BY u.name, WEEK(t.created_at)
      ) ut
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(tasks) = 52
```

The subquery generates a list of the number of tasks performed by each user in each week in the last 52 weeks. This is then grouped again in the outer query by user, and only users who have performed a task in each week will be listed as they are the only ones who will have `COUNT(tasks) = 52`

Comment: Thank you Nick for pointing me in right direction and also learned a lot from your query while solving this particular problem.

Comment: @KuldeepDangi if you didn't solve it like this you should post what you did use as an answer and accept it.